# Unable to create user and login inside of rails test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, post

I was working on my rails application's tests and noticed some of my tests were failing after I added a login feature, since the views use the current user_id from the session variable, which was undefined during testing.

I tried to remedy this by creating a post request to create a user (a user can be a professor or a student for my app) and then to login with that user inside the test:

**courses_controller_test.rb**

```
setup do
    @course = courses(:one)
    @user = professors(:admin)
end

test "should get new" do

  professor_http_code = post professors_path, params:  {professor: {firstname:@user.firstname,
                                                     lastname: @user.lastname,
                                                     email: @user.email,
                                                     password: "123456",
                                                     password_confirmation: "123456"}}

  puts "Professor post http code: " + professor_http_code.to_s
  login_http_code = post login_path, params: {email: @user.email,
                                           password: "123456",
                                           type: {field: "professor"}}
  puts "Login post http code: " + login_http_code.to_s
  get new_course_url
  assert_response :success
end
```

The test fails with the same problem (no current user when rendering the view) and produces the following output in the console:

**Console output**

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 22449
Run options: --backtrace --seed 26071

# Running:

.Professor create params: <ActionController::Parameters {"firstname"=>"foo", "lastname"=>"bar", "email"=>"foobar@gmail.com", "password"=>"123456", "password_confirmation"=>"123456"} permitted: false>
Professor not saved to db
..Professor post http code: 200
user login params: #<Professor id: 135138680, firstname: "foo", lastname: "bar", email: "foobar@gmail.com", created_at: "2020-03-31 02:12:50", updated_at: "2020-03-31 02:12:50", password_digest: nil>
Login post http code: 500
F

Failure:
CoursesControllerTest#test_should_get_new [/home/sruditsky/Homework/Capstone/team-formation-app/test/controllers/courses_controller_test.rb:25]:
Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <500: Internal Server Error>
```

And here are my session and professor controller functions which are handling the requests:

**Professors Controller**

```
class ProfessorsController < ApplicationController
...

  def create
    @professor = Professor.new(professor_params)
    puts "Professor create params: " + params[:professor].inspect
    respond_to do |format|
      if @professor.save
        puts "password_d: " + @professor.password_digest
        log_in(@professor, "professor")
        format.html { redirect_to @professor, notice: 'Professor was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @professor }
      else
        puts "Professor not saved to db"
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @professor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
...

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def professor_params
      params.require(:professor).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
```

**Sessions Controller**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

...
def create
    user = nil
    type = params[:type][:field]
    if type == "student"
      user = Student.find_by_email(params[:email])
    elsif type == "professor"
      user = Professor.find_by_email(params[:email])
    end
    puts "user login params: " + user.inspect
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      puts "logging in"
      log_in(user, type)
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged in!"
    else
      puts "invalid password"
      flash.now[:alert] = "Email or password is invalid"
      render "new"
    end
  end

...
```

The console output shows that the professor is not being saved to the database, but creating a professor account on the application works fine, and also when I type the following into the rails console in the test env it works fine:

```
app.post "/professors", params: {professor: {firstname: "foo", lastname: "bar", email: "foobar@gmail.com", password: "123456", password_confirmation: "123456"}}
```

I have tried adding a random authenticity_token to the params, hardcoding all the strings in the params instead of using the @user object, and dropping and recreating, migrating, loading, and preparing my test database and have had no luck.

Github repo: https://github.com/ditsky/team-formation-app

Let me know if you need to see something else in my application to solve the problem, and any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: Can you check whether there's a parameter coming through the POST which is not on the .permitted list that is used to validate the parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding a password digest field to my Professor fixture and skipping the creation of a user all together and instead just logging in. I am still not sure why creating the professor by posting to the professors_path did not work in my case so if anyone knows the answer to that please let me know.